# How to place the text boxes adjacent to another textbox

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to place the 2 input fields and two check boxes in row,but the input field is displaying in another row.

I tried the bootstrap classes like group-addon,
Here is my code sample:

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <input th:title="host" type="text"  class="form-control"
               th:id="host" 
                placeholder="https://example.com/" 
                th:field="hostvalue" />


        <input th:title="path" type="text" 
                class="form-control"
                th:id="Path" 
                 placeholder="https://example.com/" 
                 th:field="path" />


        <span th:title="hold" class="input-group-addon checkbox-custom">
            <input th:title="hold" 
                class="form-checkbox-custom" 
                th:id="OnHold" 
                type="checkbox" 
                aria-label="..." 
                th:field="onHold" 
                                            > 
            <label th:for="OnHold" >on hold</label>
        </span>

        <span th:title="enabled"  class="input-group-addon checkbox-custom">
            <input th:title="enabled" 
                class="form-checkbox-custom" 
                type="checkbox" 
                th:id="Enabled" 
                aria-label="..." 
                th:field="enabled" 
                />
            <label th:for="Enabled" >enabled</label>
        </span>

    </div>

 I tried adding span tag and div tag ,but still the second input box is displaying in second row.   
    I expect the output like host,url,hold,enabled fields in a row but I am getting url field in a second row.
```

Answer (score 0):

unable to reproduce the issue with the information that you provided... check the snippet below to see if you're missing something...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <input th:title="host" type="text" class="form-control" th:id="host" placeholder="https://example.com/" th:field="hostvalue" />


  <input th:title="path" type="text" class="form-control" th:id="Path" placeholder="https://example.com/" th:field="path" />


  <span th:title="hold" class="input-group-addon checkbox-custom">
            <input th:title="hold" 
                class="form-checkbox-custom" 
                th:id="OnHold" 
                type="checkbox" 
                aria-label="..." 
                th:field="onHold" 
                                            > 
            <label th:for="OnHold" >on hold</label>
        </span>

  <span th:title="enabled" class="input-group-addon checkbox-custom">
            <input th:title="enabled" 
                class="form-checkbox-custom" 
                type="checkbox" 
                th:id="Enabled" 
                aria-label="..." 
                th:field="enabled" 
                />
            <label th:for="Enabled" >enabled</label>
        </span>

</div>
```